# Array and 8x8 Matrices, Ascending Sorting, Count repeated numbers

Tags: visual-c++

I've done showing the 8x8 matrices, but I couldn't figure out how to sort them, ascending. And count the repeated numbers and it'll printf the numbers accordingly.

Exp:

Value \t Count

52   \t   1

55   \t   3

58   \t   2

and so on...

Below program is where I'm stuck at. (-.-)

```
#include <stdio.h>
void main ()
{
    int v[8][8], row, column, show, show1;

    printf ("Please enter the value for:\n");
    for(row=0; row<8; row=row+1)
    {
        printf ("\nRow %d\n", row+1);
        for(column=0; column<8; column=column+1)
        {
            printf ("Column %d\n", column+1);
            printf ("Please enter Value(v): ");
            scanf ("%d", &v[row][column]);
        }
    }
    printf ("\n");

    for (show=0; show<8; show=show+1)
    {
        printf ("|");
        for (show1=0; show1<8; show1=show1+1)
        {
            printf ("%d\t", v[show][show1]);
        }
        printf ("|");
        printf ("\n\n");
    }

    printf ("\n\nValue\tCount\n");
    for(int j=0; j<8; j++)
        for(int i=0; i<8; i++)
            v[j][i] = i*j;

    int *B = v[0];
    for(int i=0; i<64; i++)
        printf ("%d\n", B[i]);
}
```